# d3.select causes "reference error: document is not defined" in server.js file in Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make an Angular project with server-side rendering that creates D3 charts. The charts are in their own components, for example, line-chart being the folder with the ts, spec.ts, html, and css files for making a line chart. D3 is installed, and the html for the component is an svg tag-pair with an id for easy selection. However, the selection results in "ReferenceError: document is not defined" in

> ? new _selection_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["Selection"]([[document.querySelector(selector)]], [document.documentElement])

For the record, here is the minimum TypeScript code that creates this error. How do I fix this?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from "d3";

var svg = d3.select("#canvas");

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: The `d3.select("#canvas")` is referencing an element with the attribute `id=canvas` - where is that element?

Comment: It's in the component's html file. Should I have included that code? I thought explaining it in the first paragraph would be better, but I'm still not used to StackOverflow's culture.

Comment: Do you want to try putting `var svg = d3.select("#canvas");` inside ngOnInit()?

Comment: I'll try anything the skilled folks here suggest. It generates the same error, but at least I get a page instead of the server quitting. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to you svg like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  template: '<div class="chart" #chart></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
      const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
      let svg = d3.select(element)
  }

}
```

(You can leave your html in a separate file, i just put it here for clarity)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am answering this late, just for the future reference, when you run an ssr angular, and you want to render the chart in ngOnInit() method, make sure that you first check if you are on the browser first of all, in that case the document will be available. You can achieve that by doing this check beforehand:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  template: '<div class="chart" #chart></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {
  private platformId: object;

  @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    this.platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) { // add this condition to check if you are in the browser before rending the chart
      const element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
      let svg = d3.select(element)
     }
  }

}
```

**Explanation:**
Whenever angular universal renders, it first render the server side, and then it renders the browser version after that, you understand that on the server side we miss the DOM, that's why when you run `d3.select` will throw an error saying that document is not available.You can read more [Angular Universal official docs](https://angular.io/guide/universal)